# Preventing restoration of first responder

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, uikit

If a view is first responder when the view controller is popped off a `UINavigationController` stack, even if the first responder is resigned in `-viewWillDisappear:` or `UINavigationControllerDelegate`'s `-navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`, when the same view controller is pushed back on to the navigation stack the first responder is restored. I think this might be new behaviour in iOS 11.

In my case I reconfigure the view controller and don't want the first responder to be restored, but there seems to be no easy way to prevent this. I can prevent it by doing the following in the view controller (which is the delegate of the `UITextField`'s):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // do not begin editing when transitioning from/to this view controller.
    // UINavigationController restores the previous input view first responder, we don't want that, this stops it
    return self.transitionCoordinator == nil;
}
```

However, this causes a small animation where the view is scrolled slightly to accommodate for the keyboard appearing before `-textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` is called, after which it animates back. In addition the table view containing the text field cannot be scrolled to the top, as the scroll position is restored at the text field. The only option seems to be setting the scroll position in `-viewDidAppear:`, resulting in the scroll occurring after the view has appeared.

Is there a better way to prevent this?

Comment: I've worked around this by re-creating the view controller every time I want to display it, but this is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I figured out that if you resign the first responder after the presentation of the presented view controller has begun you will get the first responder restored. If you call it before it won't get restored. Getting `viewWillAppear:` or any other appearance method called means the presentation (or transition rather) started.

Resign the first responder before calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:` or any other presentation/transition method. I didn't try it for segues but I'm guessing you can resign in `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

Hope this helps.